# Asignar nombres dinámicos en las variables con Python

Tags: python

```
variable_1 = 1
variable_2 = 2
for i in [1,2]:
    print(variable_i)
```

Me gustaría saber como puedo llamar a las variables variable_i de forma genérica en Python y hacer que el código anterior funcione. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido Lourdes LB a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Lo que buscas, si bien posible, es una mala práctica. Para lo que buscas tienes estructuras como listas o diccionarios.

Comment: Lo que pides se podría hacer con _"metaprogramación"_. Pero es tan complicado en python que, supongo, lo que buscas es otra cosa.

Answer (score 2):

Para tales fines existen las listas (arreglos en otros lenguajes).

Una lista es un grupo de valores con un mismo nombre (el nombre de la lista). Para diferenciar un valor de otro, usas un índice entre `[]`.

Aunque puedes guardar cualquier combinación de objetos en una lista, para estos fines se supone que todos los elementos son del mismo tipo y significado (por ejemplo, temperatura ambiente por hora).

Tu código expresado con listas es:

```
variable = [1, 2]
for var in variable:
    print(var)
```

Explicación:

```
variable = [1, 2]
```

crea un objeto llamado `variable` y lo inicializa con una lista de dos valores (1 y 2).

También podrías crear la lista vacía y luego agregar nuevos elementos:

```
variable = [] # lista vacia
variable.append(1)
variable.append(2)
```

Sin importar como la crees, puedes acceder a los elementos usando el índice. El primer elemento tiene el índice cero; el segundo, el indice 1, y asi sucesivamente:

```
variable[0] para el primer elemento
variable[1] para el segundo elemento
```

reemplazar un valor (ojo, solo reemplazo):

```
variable[3] = "nuevo valor"
```

o usarlo en otra parte:

```
impuesto = monto * variable[4]
```

Y con listas puedes hacer una infinidad de cosas en Python.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes una solución:

```py
variable_1 = 1
variable_2 = 2
for i in [1,2]:
    print(locals()[f"variable_{i}"])
```

Las variables del dentro del mismo `scope` se encuentran en el método `locales()` como atributos diccionario.

Como dice un compañero no es un código recomendable para `newbies` pero si es cierto que en seun que paquetes o módulos muy avanzados puedes encontrarte sintaxis semejante a esa, o con `globales()`.